# Geometric Intuition for Ample Divisors and Ample Line Bundles

Tags: algebraic-geometry, divisors-algebraic-geometry, line-bundles

We know that a very ample divisor gives us an embedding into projective space and that very ample divisors are exactly the hyperplane sections.

Is there a similar geometric intuition for ample divisors? I know that a line bundle is ample if and only if some tensored power of it is very ample, so a divisor is ample if $\exists n$ such that $nD \sim H$ for $H$ a hyperplane. But can I already get a map into projective space from an ample divisor that is, let's say injective, or an immersion?

Comment: Ample divisors may have no sections. Take a degree one divisor on a smooth projective curve of large genus.

Comment: To add some context to Mohan's comment: this is one of those times in mathematics where you start with a property that makes a great deal of intuitive sense (in this case very ampleness) but has poor formal properties, and replace it with a property that is less intuitive but better behaved on the formal end of things (e.g. ampleness). This is kind of similar to how we study the intuitive but poorly behaved category of varieties by embedding it in the less intuitive but nicely behaved category of schemes.